# Conditional required properties in interface

Tags: typescript

I'd like to type an object that can contain any property, but if it has any of the properties `a`, `b` or `c`, it must contain all of the properies `a`, `b` and `c`.

In other words: the object can contain any property, but if it contains `a`, `b` or `c` it must contain `a`, `b` **and** `c`.

```
let something: Something;

// these should be valid:
something = { a: 1, b: 1, c:, 1 };
something = { a: 1, b: 1, c:, 1, custom: 'custom' };
something = { custom: 'custom' };

// these should be invalid:
something = { a: 1 };
something = { a: 1, b: 1 };
something = { a: 1, c: 1 };
something = { b: 1 };
something = { a: 1, custom: 'custom' };
```

How can this be achieved?

Creating a union type with an object seems correct, but doesn't work:

```
interface RequiredProps {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;
}

type Something = RequiredProps | {};
```

Comment: probably it is better to have union of two types or even just `any` and then use type check to limit type to something concrete.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a union type, between a type that allows `a`, `b`, `c` and an indexer, and one that forces  `a`, `b`, and `c` if present to have type `never`.

```
 type Something = ({ a: number, b: number, c: number } & { [n: string]: any }) |
    ( { a?: never, b?: never, c?: never } &{ [n: string]: any });
```

If you have functions that return `never` it may be possible to assign the properties but for most practical cases this should work.

We could even create a generic type for this situation:

```
type RequireAll<TOptional, TRequired> = (TOptional & TRequired) | (Partial<Record<keyof TOptional, never>> & TRequired)
type Something = RequireAll<{a: number, b: number, c:number}, {[n:string]:any}>
```

Comment: These TOptional and TRequired sound confusing, I'd suggest the wording T and TAllOrNone instead: `export type AllOrNone<T, TAllOrNone> = (T & TAllOrNone) | (T & Partial<Record<keyof TAllOrNone, never>>);`

Comment: Works fine when the initializing the variable but looks like now working when trying to discriminate the specific subtype... I'll prepare the [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74192721/4818123).