# Enforce at compile time that exactly one of two props is specified?

Tags: typescript

I have a styled `Button` component.

```
interface Button {
    href?: string;
    action(): void;
}
```

I want a consumer of this Button to pass either (XOR) `href` or `action` as prop, not both.

I want TypeScript to enforce this at compile time.

How can I do this?

Comment: This seems like a generally bad idea - now you have to check *everywhere* whether this is a `Button` with an `href` or a `Button` with an `action`. Why not make two interfaces (e.g. `Action` and `Link`), and have things that must accept either kind take the union `Action | Link`?

Comment: refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49265354/194345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a union type to specify that the type can have either one prop or the other

```
type Button = {
    href: string;
    action?: never
} | {
    action: () => void;
    href?: never;
}

let b1: Button = { href: "" };
let b2: Button = { action: () => { } };
let b3: Button = { action: () => { }, href: "" }; // error
```

You need to add the optional `never` props to ensure you get an error, this is due to  the way excess property checks work you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722138/typescript-arrays-using-mixed-types-inference/52722384#52722384). You could also use the `StrictUnion` type in that answer, but for just two properties it might be overkill.