# How to discriminate the specific subtype in conditionally required properties of TypeScript interface / type alias?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

The TypeScript type checking works fine for initializing of the object variable of type

```js
type Something = ({ a: number, b: number, c: number } & { [n: string]: any }) |
    ( { a?: never, b?: never, c?: never } & { [n: string]: any });
```

from the question [Conditional required properties in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49265104/4818123), but looks like does not works when we are trying to discriminate the subtype. I'll omit the `{ [n: string]: any })` part for the below example.

```js
type Something = ({ a: number, b: number, c: number }) |
    ( { a?: never, b?: never, c?: never });

function test(parameter: Something): void {

  if (typeof parameter.a !== "undefined") {
    // Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
    parameter.b.toFixed()
  }

}
```

The type checking like

```js
typeof parameter.a !== "undefined" &&
typeof parameter.b !== "undefined" &&
typeof parameter.c !== "undefined"
```

actually means that there is no "conditional requirement" here.

Any solutions?

Comment: Typescript does not provide facilities for dynamic typing like this.  At runtime when you are doing this check, all objects are effectively plain javascript and the information you are interested in is lost in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [user-defined-type-guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgDRQm6GkXUDGdxZ5UAvgNwCwAUANCRY8AEIp0WOhABujGjPlUoLfHIpc%20g-sOgBlAPZEIwABYBLPAHNJcSEgA%20oyGO0CBAMwJ4mwC4Z4UBYAzvaIABRWYATAuEYm5lbWAJS40bHBIS6I6AJQUOSmBORBGcAAdJhQAITIqD4AJhCeVhCN2pwe-N6%20-oFQwBAhwBFgmOSYiRTxxqaWNmlQsoYWjXk6BRaeUFFh8AhjE1OmFCkpGwUFTIEhhgA2EBX3htZHk9PkFSQVwIYAYhYAB7tCLnbQFThQCD3ELQND5K43PB3R7PV4RABEAEk8DFgFkoIYdnooGJMSlEV0dNSBMiRoMDrj8bhwkhUBgcFAAGzUWhQAAczGwAEYAAxcbpDEYRPQIZmxFLcIA)

```js
type TypeA = { a: number, b: number, c: number };

type TypeB = { a: never, b: never, c: never };

type Something = TypeA | TypeB;


function isTypeA(input: Something): input is TypeA {
  // your custom logic here
  return input.a !== undefined;
}

function test(parameter: Something): void {

  if (isTypeA(parameter)) {
    console.log(parameter.b.toFixed());
  } else {
    console.log("Input is of type B")
  }

}

const typeAInput: TypeA = { a: 6, b: 8, c:10 }

test(typeAInput);
```